# How to change chance of spawn based on distance?

Tags: procedural-generation, random

I am trying to make a cellular automate cave but want to keep the middle empty.

How should I change the chance based on the distance from the middle?

I don't want to completely deny it just want a small enough chance to keep it almost empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think along the lines of uneven distribution. For example squaring the random value:

```
if Sqr(Random) > (1 - NormalizedDistanceFromCenter) then AddMonster
```

will give you a nice squared distribution:

```
Distance | Chance
---------|------
0        | 0%
0.2      | 11%
0.4      | 23%
0.6      | 37%
0.8      | 55%
0.9      | 69%
1.0      | 100%
```

Comment: I made a different approach :

if ( Math.random() > 1-0.8*(Math.abs(half_distance*0.5-distance)/distance) ) {
     
    }